# DBI/Spark: how to store the result in a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: sql, r, apache-spark, sparklyr, r-dbi

I am using `sparklyr` to run some analysis, but I am interested also in writing raw `SQL` queries using `DBI`.

I am able to run the following query

```
query <- "SELECT col1, FROM mydata WHERE some_condition"
dataframe <- dbGetQuery(spark_connection, query)
```

but this returns the data into R (in a dataframe).

What I want instead is keep the data inside Spark and store it in another *Spark Dataframe* for further interaction with `sparklyr`.

Any ideas?

Comment: The issue with using DBI is memory. You wont be able to fetch a huge amount of data with that. If your query results return a huge amount of data, the will overwhelm spark's driver memory and cause out of memory errors... Thus if you want to use it to return small dataset, you don't need spark for the matter.

Comment: no that's the point. I want to work on Spark dataframes and keep the data in spark. Only later one, after few more SQL queries I will pull the data in R.

Comment: Then DBI isn't the solution for you; you ought using regular SparkR if you want to stick with R for that

Comment: wait, I dont get your point. I thought DBI was able to run SQL queries on Spark Dataframes. After all, sparklyr is doing exactly that: translating queries into SQL commands.

Comment: That's not what's happening with sparklyr, DBI runs the sql command a returns an R DataFrame which means it is collecting the data to materialize it in a regular R context.

Comment: OK. thanks, but what about `dbSendQuery` then?

Comment: dbSendQuery doesn't extract any records... I think it's used to cache tables, create views and such (Hive Query Language DSL)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146904/discussion-between-eliasah-and-noobie).

Comment: cannot use the chat unfortunately. but if you have some suggestions in mind, I would be very happy to know them! feel free to post an answer! thanks @eliasah!

Comment: It's ok. I'm sorry I don't have suggestion besides what I have already said. I use sparklyr with dplyr/ggplot and that does the job for me. For spark-sql, I'd rather use the spark scala API. It's more complete and stable.

Comment: do you know a good tutorial for the scala spark api?

Comment: My personal opinion, you need to start with official documentation for Spark and for scala, you might want to consider something simple http://scalacookbook.com/

Comment: I've compounded my comments in the form of an answer. You can accept it so other might consider it correct when looking for the same thing. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with using `DBI` is memory. You wont be able to fetch a huge amount of data with that. If your query results return a huge amount of data, the will overwhelm spark's driver memory and cause out of memory errors...

What's happening with sparklyr is the following. `DBI` runs the `sql` command a returns an R `DataFrame` which means it is collecting the data to materialize it in a regular R context.

Thus if you want to use it to return small dataset, you don't need spark for the matter.

Then *DBI isn't the solution for you*; you ought using regular `SparkR` if you want to stick with R for that.

This is an example on how you can use the `sql` in `sparkr` :

```
sc %>% spark_session %>% 
   invoke("sql", "SELECT 1") %>% 
   invoke("createTempView", "foo")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also do:

```
mydata_spark_df <- tbl(sc, sql("select * from mydata"))
```